# Java: How to post this XML request?

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications

i'm working with SOA using WebServices.
So i need to send a XML request to receive another XML with the response.

I create this class:

```
package com.ws.test;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SendXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String strSOAP = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";

            strSOAP += "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope ";

            strSOAP += " xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

            strSOAP += " xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/";

            strSOAP += " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

            strSOAP += " xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

            strSOAP += " xmlns:ns=\"urn:bacnet_ws\">";

            strSOAP += " <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">";

            strSOAP += " <ns:getValue>";

            strSOAP += " <ns:options></ns:options>";

            strSOAP += " <ns:path>/.sysinfo/.vendor-name</ns:path>";

            strSOAP += " </ns:getValue>";

            strSOAP += " </SOAP-ENV:Body>";

            strSOAP += "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";


            //Create socket
            String hostname = "192.168.1.2";
            int port = 8080;
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
            Socket sock = new Socket(addr, port);

            //Send header
            String path = "/rcx-ws/rcx";
            BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            // You can use "UTF8" for compatibility with the Microsoft virtual machine.
            wr.write("POST " + path + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
            wr.write("Host: 192.168.1.2\r\n");
            wr.write("Content-Length: " + strSOAP.length() + "\r\n");
            wr.write("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n");
            wr.write("\r\n");

            //Send data
            wr.write(strSOAP);
            wr.flush();

            // Response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not right because i receive this message error:

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>   Server: gSOAP/2.7 Content-Type:
>   text/xml; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Length: 570 Connection: close
>
> SOAP-ENV:VersionMismatchSOAP
>   version mismatch or invalid SOAP
>   message

I need to send this parameter to the another system :

```
strSOAP += " <ns:getValue>";

strSOAP += " <ns:options></ns:options>";

strSOAP += " <ns:path>/.sysinfo/.vendor-name</ns:path>";

strSOAP += " </ns:getValue>";
```

How i could do that in Java ?

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Comment: This is a crazy way of using web services. You really need to be using a proper webservice client framework, not posting hand-crafted XML strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using sockets to transmit data, you'll have to look at the [SOAP specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap/). For example, SOAP 1.1 requires the [SOAPAction HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528). Use a tool like [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to check the validity of requests before you start writing code.

In general, you'd be better off using an existing client API (of which there are a few to choose). For example, you can easily use [hand-crafted soap requests with JAX-WS](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2011/04/java-jax-ws-web-services-and-clients.html#ws_dynamic).

*A couple of notes:*

---

The code leaks resources. [Close](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close%28%29) your streams. See the [try/finally pattern](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/10/java-how-not-to-make-mess-of-stream.html).

---

```
BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(
                     new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
//...
wr.write("Content-Length: " + strSOAP.length() + "\r\n");
```

This would not be safe for code points above U+007F as `String.length()` returns the number of code units in UTF-16. `Content-Length` should contain the length in `byte`s; not Java `char`s.

Answer (score 1):

Good lord dude. Not to be overly sarcastic, but haven't you heard of [JAX-WS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Web_Services)? [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jax-rs)? Or even the humble, but reliable [JAX-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-RPC)? How could you be working on web-service based SOA if you are actually trying to build a web service request by hand like that, in such a paleolithic way.

I mean, c'mon, I know we shouldn't tell people to 'google it', but seriously, did it ever occur to you to do a google on 'web service call example' before trying that coding madness? This is 2011, not 1994-95 when most people didn't know what a web search was.

I suggest you start with the [Java EE 5 JAX-WS tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/?wp405739&JAXWS.html#wp72279) as there is much for you to learn. Good luck.

Comment: thanks by your comment Luis,and no nobody tell about JAX-WS or others things about you said, that's why i ask for help.
thanks anyway.